# Discrepancy between Google PageSpeed field data and lab data despite no recent changes. Why are they not matching?

Tags: next.js, pagespeed-insights

I am facing an issue with Google PageSpeed Insights where the field data (representing real-world user experience) and lab data (simulated environment) do not match up. This inconsistency has persisted for the past three months, despite no recent changes to my website. Here is the 2 types example -

1. Field data is **poor** but lab data is **good** - https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-accuride-com-en-us/1nrqitpy4d?form_factor=desktop
   [image]
2. Field data is **good** but lab is is **poor** - https://www.accuride.com/en-us/products/drawer-slides/heavy-duty-slides
   [image]

To troubleshoot this issue, I have tried various approaches such as clearing cache, testing from different devices and locations, and even validating the results using alternative performance measurement tools. Unfortunately, these efforts have not provided any clarification on why the field data and lab data continue to differ significantly.

I'm reaching out to the Stack Overflow community to seek advice and potential explanations for this discrepancy. Has anyone else encountered a similar situation? Could there be any underlying factors or technical considerations that might contribute to such a discrepancy between Google PageSpeed field data and lab data? Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: The top screenshot implies the content is not being rendered. This could be why the test showed good results.

Comment: The top screenshot implies the content is not being rendered. If the page is not rendered then why page speed tool showing us a result? Can you suggest any other tool is giving a rendered page report?

Comment: The Rich Result Test also does not display your video. https://search.google.com/test/rich-results/result?id=UMC6hC_PwdEyEy1EPyymIA

Check to see if resources are not loaded, causing a better test score.